# arecord | split to wav or ogg

Tags: linux, audio, wav, flac

I have the following script on linux:

```
arecord -t raw -f S16_LE -r 44100  -c 1 | split -d -b 882000 --filter='flac - -f --endian little --sign signed --channels 1 --bps 2  --sample-rate 44100 -s -o "${FILE}.flac"'
```

this script records audio at 44100 fs, 1 channel, then flac files with 882000 bytes, ie 10 seconds of audio at 44100 sample rate are created and saved. The audios are 2 mb, is there any way I can do this but save it in wav or ogg format?
Flac files, not having loss, take up a lot of memory space, I want to reduce that with another format

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lame](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAME) instead flac:

```
arecord -t raw -f S16_LE -r 44100  -c 1 | split -d -b 882000 --filter='lame -r -s 44.1 - "${FILE}.mp3"'
```